# Best way to package multiple jQuery templates in single xHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, templates, jquery-templates

> **Update:** after another day of digging
>   into this issue, I have found that the
>   current jQuery template lib provides
>   no way to do this. [this article](http://encosia.com/2010/12/02/jquery-templates-composite-rendering-and-remote-loading/)
>   describes a good approach.
>
> I would still like to hear of any
>   additional thoughts on doing this. The
>   article linked above requires that the
>   returned string of templates be
>   inserted into the DOM. Seems as though
>   leaving the DOM out of this would be
>   ideal, and less overhead on the
>   browser. Imagine a large page, with
>   multiple composite templates that may
>   not get used. Although, maybe because
>   the templates are wrapped in a script
>   tag, there is only a single DOM item per template? Come on, let's
>   hear some thoughts...

Using [jQuery template libs](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/), what's the best way to combine multiple, related, relatively small templates together? Do you need a single `<script>` tag for each individual template? What about in the case of dynamically pulling these templates via AJAX? Can I combine these templates somehow?

Consider the following:

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    {{tmpl "#titleTemplate"}}
    <tr class="detail"><td>Director: ${Director}</td></tr>
</script>

<script id="titleTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <tr class="title"><td>${Name}</td></tr>
</script>
```

Now because these two templates are very closely related (and one depends on the other) it would make sense to consolidate these into a single AJAX call, and get them both at once. I have a few ideas, but I'd like to know if there is common/best way to do this? Currently I pull in a chunk of HTML, and then do a .find() to get the specific peice of HTML for a template... e.g.:

```
var templatePackage = fancyAjaxCalltoGetTemplates();
```

"templatePackage" might then look like this:

```
<div id="templatePkg"> 
    <div id="movieTemplate">
    {{tmpl "#titleTemplate"}}
      <tr class="detail"><td>Director: ${Director}</td></tr>
    </div>    

    <div id="titleTemplate">
    <tr class="title"><td>${Name}</td></tr>
    </div>
</div>
```

I could then do:

```
var titleTemplate = jQuery.template('titleTemplate', $(templatePackage).find('#titleTemplate') );
```

and

```
var movieTemplate = jQuery.template('movieTemplate', $(templatePackage).find('#movieTemplate') );
```

...let me know what you think... what would you do?

Comment: i could also use a delimiter, and split a group of templates from a single response. but there must be a more elegant way to do this with jquery/templates - am i missing something from the templates documentation?

Comment: I _think_ I'm following you here... are you just trying to get around the problem of having to load ALL the template(s) into your rendered page first, then only choose out the few you need?

Comment: Thats right. I need to dynamically load templates as required.

Comment: I added an approach to this that I think is flexible enough to handle all your requirements, let me know what you think and we can work on it together.

Answer (score 4):

I like the referenced article in your update, except the assumption that you can't cache templates unless you insert them into the DOM.  From the [jQuery.tmpl documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/),

"To cache the template when using markup that is obtained from a string (rather than from inline markup in the page), use `$.template( name, markup )` to create a named template for reuse. See [jQuery.template()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.template)."

Using this, we can build a javascript template management system that allows us to load as many templates at a time as we need while keeping the DOM clean.  On the client, keep a hash of template objects by name.  You can use your favorite object based javascript pattern here, but I would think the structure could be like this:

```
templates[templateName] = {
    templateMarkup: markupFromServer,
    loadedAt: Date.now(),
    compiledTemplateFunction: jQuery.template( templateName, markupFromServer )
}
```

Then use the templates to generate HTML like this:

```
templates['unique-name'].compiledTemplateFunction(inputData)
```

Then, build an unload mechanism to free up memory:

```
function unload(templateName) {
    delete templates[templateName];
    delete jquery.template[templateName];
}
```

Most importantly, you now have a method of storing multiple templates so you can make requests like: `$.get('/TemplateManagement/Render', arrayOfTemplateNamesToLoad, loadManyTemplatesSuccess)` to load multiple templates at a time.  The only thing we need is a controller `TemplateManagement` that will take an array of template names as an input and return JSON that pairs a template name with its markup.  There are a few ways to do this but it seems to me the most convenient is to define partial views for each template.  In ASP.NET MVC 3, you can use [this technique](http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/) and `RenderPartial` to emit each template's markup into a JSON response.  You can either name the partial views the same as the templates or map the names in some custom way.

Comment: yay, ::pats self on back::.  This is my favorite answer.  It's gonna catch on someday and it'll make the world a better place :)

Comment: This is exactly the approach I'd take.  Pat yourself on the back again =)

Answer (score 2):

OK, I read the article you reference in this post.  As I see it, his way is probably one of the best ways to load up the template page(s).  The only thing I don't like is the asynchronous problems that could crop up, esp. if you need to immediately do some templating before the async get returns... plus any binding issues that could happen before it returns something.  In several projects I have done I use his "ancient" SSI (server side includes), but I just use something even easier like:

`<% Response.WriteFile("this_page_template_file.html"); %>`

You could put it anywhere where you'd place a  tag.  Like he says, just put in only the templates you need, or maybe include two templates: one is a "base" template with commonly-used items and the second one would have the page-specific ones with template references {{tmpl}}.

Is this even close to an answer?  ;-)

Comment: Is that what you ended up doing? Your server side page decides and response.writes the template files? I am also looking for a good, clean solution for this problem

Comment: I haven't yet, but I intend to go back and re-design later (have to push this project out now). I want it to be something whereby I can load only the things I need for that particular page, but right now the performance is good enough such that it works well, just not elegantly. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 2):

[First off, great question. I love this topic]

I have no experience with the plugin "jquery-template-libs", but there is a particular lightweight javascript template plugins that are becoming almost a standard and plays very nicely with jQuery, which is probably better suited for the task than JTL, Mustache:

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

It's got something that's called a "partial" which is essentially a way to include smaller templates within another one. Which sounds like it will help you out a lot.

On top of that there is a library called ICanHaz.js:

http://icanhazjs.com/

ICanHaz essentially extends Mustache to include built in functionality for  templates and works incredibly well.

Mustache/ICanHaz allow you to add templates by variable, by a json call or by using  tags. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but you might want to take a look at [Closure-Templates](http://code.google.com/p/closure-templates/). They provide the kind of functionality you're after with the added advantage of being compiled into JavaScript at compile-time instead of at run-time in each user's browser.

If you do decide to look into using them then I'd suggest using [plovr](http://plovr.com/) for building them.